# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl$1

Tags: android, build.gradle, aapt2

I've updated android targetSDkVersion to 28, after that getting following error.

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Build.Gradle

```
ext {
        sdkVersion = 28
        minSdkVersion = 21
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportVersion = '27.1.0'
        playVersion = '12.0.0'
        wearVersion = '2.0.5'
        butterknifeVersion = '9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
        jacksonVersion = '2.9.0'
        daggerVersion = '2.4'
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Please post your whole app-level `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

Use latest versions for all the dependencies used in the gradle file. In my case, the error got vanished after changing dependency versions to their latest.

Answer (score 0):

anytime you get 'Program type already present', there are two instances of it getting compiled from your decencies.

So, check `./gradlew app:dependencies`

Figure out what is duplicating that particular `android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator`.

It could be one of your direct dependencies or any of the third party dependencies that uses the same v4 support library.